# java Swing Listeners: components listening at each others

Tags: java, swing, events, event-handling, jlist

I want to code two JList (categories and items). When I click one category it should select all the items for that category and when I click on one item it should select its categories. So both [JList](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) will have a [ListSelectionListener](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionListener.html) listening at each other and changing the selection.

Should I fear about some a kind of "**loop**" ? Is there a way to tell that an Event has been consumed ? how do people manage that kind of situation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have imagined, each time make selection on `listA`, you will trigger a `ListSelectionEvent` to be fired on your listener for `listA`, whose job it is to find all appropriate items in `listB` to select.  Forcing selection then on `listB` will trigger events to be handled by your `listB` listener.  This will in turn force selection on `listA`.  Simply using two listeners doesnt solve the problem.

I see two options:

1 - use a single listener.  This listener will need to test the source of the event by using the `getSource` method on the `ListSelectionEvent`.  If the source is `listB`, remove your listener from the listenerlist of `listA`, force selection on `listA` and then readd.

```
list1.removeListSelectionListener(this);
list1.setSelectedIndex(e.getFirstIndex()); //this would have to be played with to allow for intervals
list1.addListSelectionListener(this);`
```

2 - use two listeners,  however, to avoid the loop, you would need to test whether the item is already selected before attempting to select it.  If it is already selected, dont reselect it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Beans Binding API](https://beansbinding.dev.java.net/). Here's a [tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-binding.html#intro) for NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

Two Listeners is good way how to do that, don't worry. Just be sure you create listeners only ONCE, not in loop.

Answer (score -1):

Check where your focus is. If your listener listens to component A and the focus is not on A, do not update other components as A is not the component changed by the user.

Comment: no - focus is not a good flag (f.i. selection might happen programatically ...)

Comment: Not in his case. I think relying on the focus is a good way to implement this without any unnecessary overhead. He was talking about "do something in comp X" => "update Y". He didn't mention to change these components programmatically.

Comment: shrugs - you are free to stick to your errors, after all it'll be _your_ pain when suffering the consequences of coding so short-sighted ;-)

Comment: Again, he didn't mention to change things programmatically. You can code dynamic as much as you want but in this case it isn't needed. But I can understand it's not the most clean solution. The accepted answer isn't perfect either, because in case of N components, you will need to remove N-1 listeners and then readd them. Do you think that's clean?